# Is there a way to handle the last case differently in a Scala for loop?

Tags: scala

For example suppose I have

```
  for (line <- myData) {
    println("}, {")
  }
```

Is there a way to get the last line to print

```
println("}")
```

Comment: As @Nicolas's answer already indicates, it's frequently a lot easier if you can refactor your desired behaviour to act differently for the *first* iteration, rather than the last. It's trivial to identify the first iteration.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Before going any further, I'd recommend you avoid `println` in a for-comprehension.  It can sometimes be useful for tracking down a bug that occurs in the middle of a collection, but otherwise leads to code that's harder to refactor and test.

More generally, life usually becomes easier if you can restrict where *any* sort of side-effect occurs. So instead of:

```
for (line <- myData) {
  println("}, {")
}
```

You can write:

```
val lines = for (line <- myData) yield "}, {"
println(lines mkString "\n")
```

I'm also going to take a guess here that you wanted the content of each line in the output!

```
val lines = for (line <- myData) yield (line + "}, {")
println(lines mkString "\n")
```

Though you'd be better off still if you just used `mkString` directly - that's what it's for!

```
val lines = myData.mkString("{", "\n}, {", "}")
println(lines)
```

Note how we're first producing a `String`, then printing it in a single operation.  This approach can easily be split into separate methods and used to implement `toString` on your class, or to inspect the generated String in tests.

Answer (score 29):

Can you refactor your code to take advantage of built-in `mkString`?

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).mkString("{", "}, {", "}")
res1: String = {1}, {2}, {3}
```

Answer (score 15):

I agree fully with what has been said before about using `mkstring`, and distinguishing the first iteration rather than the last one. Would you still need to distinguish on the last, scala collections have an `init` method, which return all elements but the last. 
So you can do

```
for(x <- coll.init) workOnNonLast(x)
workOnLast(coll.last)
```

(`init` and `last` being sort of the opposite of head and tail, which are the first and and all but first). Note however than depending on the structure, they may be costly. On `Vector`, all of them are fast. On `List`, while head and tail are basically free, `init` and `last` are both linear in the length of the list. `headOption` and `lastOption` may help you when the collection may be empty, replacing `workOnlast` by

```
for (x <- coll.lastOption) workOnLast(x)
```

Comment: If your collection may be empty, use `dropRight(1)` instead of `init`

Answer (score 6):

You may take the [addString](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L281) function of the `TraversableOnce`trait as an example.

```
def addString(b: StringBuilder, start: String, sep: String, end: String): StringBuilder = {
  var first = true

  b append start   
  for (x <- self) {
    if (first) {
      b append x
      first = false
    } else {
      b append sep
      b append x
    }
  }
  b append end

  b
}
```

In your case, the separator is `}, {` and the end is `}`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use built-in mkString function, you can make something like

```
for (line <- lines)
  if (line == lines.last) println("last")
  else println(line)
```

**UPDATE:** As [didierd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754787/didierd) mentioned in comments, this solution is wrong because last value can occurs several times, he provides better solution in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144275/is-there-a-way-to-handle-the-last-case-differently-in-a-scala-for-loop/7144956#7144956).

It is fine for `Vectors`, because `last` function takes "effectively constant time" for them, as for `Lists`, it takes linear time, so you can use pattern matching

```
@tailrec
def printLines[A](l: List[A]) {
  l match {
    case Nil => 
    case x :: Nil => println("last")
    case x :: xs => println(x); printLines(xs)
  }
}
```

Comment: The recursive solution is fine. The one with == lines.last is wrong unless you know the value of the last element occurs nowhere else.

Comment: @didierd thanks, I missed it. I pointed the mistake in the answer.

Comment: I tried it using `eq` instead of `==` and it still doesn't work - the Strings must get cached, which is a bit of a pain

Comment: @Luigi Plinge, I tried `eq` too. That's true, strings are caching. But I like @didierd solution with `init` and `lastOption`. It is more elegant than if-else.

Comment: @4e6 I wanted to mention init/last because they are spot on the question "how to handle the last element differently" and really easy to use, but if the collection is a List, your tailrec solution will certainly be more efficient (when efficiency is a concern).

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are rightfully pointed to `mkString`, and for a normal amount of data I would also use that.

However, `mkString` builds (accumulates) the end-result in-memory through a `StringBuilder`. This is not always desirable, depending on the amount of data we have.

In this case, if all we want is to "print" we don't need to build the big-result first (and maybe we even want to avoid this).

Consider the implementation of this helper function:

```
def forEachIsLast[A](iterator: Iterator[A])(operation: (A, Boolean) => Unit): Unit = {
  while(iterator.hasNext) {
    val element = iterator.next()
    val isLast = !iterator.hasNext // if there is no "next", this is the last one
    operation(element, isLast)
  }
}
```

It iterates over all elements and invokes `operation` passing each element in turn, with a boolean value. The value is `true` if the element passed is the **last one**.

In your case it could be used like this:

```
forEachIsLast(myData) { (line, isLast) =>
  if(isLast)
    println("}")
  else
    println("}, {")
}
```

We have the following advantages here:

- It operates on each element, one by one, without necessarily accumulating the result in memory (unless you want to).
- Because it does not need to load the whole collection into memory to check its size, it's enough to ask the Iterator if it's exhausted or not. You could read data from a big file, or from the network, etc.

Comment: Or, slightly more elegantly, maybe: `forEachIsLast` can just be `val it = seq.toIterator
    it.foreach {operation(_, it.hasNext)}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @TheArchetypalPaul! Edited my answer to use an implementation based on your suggestion.